# Sending Parse Push notification from iOS app to Android app

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am creating an app for iOS and android.

I am using parse for push notification.

I get notification from iOS to iOS and android to android, but am not receiving notification from iOS to android or android to iOS.

I would really appreciate if you can help!

Comment: Maybe this can help u, good luck. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: Thanks @Justlike! Actually I am using Parse Push notification framework. Can you help me how to use parse for sending cross device push notification.

Comment: Thx @iturki

var push = PFPush()
push.setQuery(pushQuery)
let data = ["alert":"message"]
push.setData(data)
push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock({ (s:Bool, e:NSError?) -> Void in    
    if s{
        //sent
    }else{
        //not sent
    }
})

Comment: @TechBee Sorry, I've never used Parse Push notification framework.